# MOSFET symbol - direction of source terminal

Tags: transistors, schematics, nmos, pmos

There are two possible illustrations of MOSFETs : with an arrow, and without an arrow.

example for NMOS with arrow :

[image]

example for NMOS without arrow :

[image]

example for PMOS with arrow :

[image]

example for PMOS without arrow :

[image]

For case of schematic with arrow, I could make a 180 degrees rotation without any problem : I will still recognize the source and the drain.

For the case of the schematic without arrow, I have no more way to recognize where is the source.

So my question is : for the schematic without the arrow, is the source of NMOS always at the bottom, and is the source of the PMOS always at the top ?

Comment: The source should always be explicitly marked on the schematic symbol with an arrow that also shows the channel type.  Where are you seeing these symbols?

Comment: see for example :https://www.circuitbread.com/tutorials/how-to-read-a-mosfet-symbol

Comment: Those symbols do not look like standard MOSFET symbols to me. The source and drain need to be clearly indicated in some way, do not assume "up or down".

Comment: The source and drain are functionally interchangeable; the only reason an arrow is required is if the source is also tied to the substrate. So, the symbols with arrows are typically used for discrete transistors, where such a connection exists, and the symbols without arrows are typically used in IC schematics, where the substrate is connected to a common point on the chip.

Comment: The point is that depending on $V_{GS}$, the behaviour of a *circuit schematic* is not the same if we change S by D, so if it is not written, we should know where is the source.

Comment: example of wikipedia for logic circuit with NMOS : the source and drain are not written : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NMOS_logic

Comment: other example : https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece110/sp2021/content/courseNotes/files/?logicAndCMOS   figure 2, 3, 4, 5 : no arrow written. So there should be a *convention* ?

Comment: Don't assume a convention such as "left = source" or "down = source".  As @DaveTweed said, in these types of circuits, the source and drain are interchangeable, all you need to know for the analysis is that the device becomes a short (or open, for depletion mode) when activated.

Comment: @MathieuKrisztian .... double dollar sign works in comments ...  `$$V_{GS}$$` ... $$V_{GS}$$

Comment: The image for 'PMOS with arrow' is not correct, the arrow should be pointing inwards. At the moment it is showing an upside-down NMOS.

Comment: @BrtH : would you have a link on the web that shows the correct image for this, and stating that it is a PMOS ?

Comment: @MathieuKrisztian https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOSFET#Circuit_symbols (https://i.imgur.com/qIjjKmc.png)

Comment: @BrtH : it is not 100 % sure that you are right, because the arrow is not on the same *position* : for my schematic : it is on the source, while in your example, it is on the gate, so it is *still possible* than the two schematics would be both correct. What is your opinion ?

Comment: @MathieuKrisztian the symbol in the fourth column (above the text 'no bulk') has it in the same style as you, on the source. They are not both correct, the image in this question is wrong.

Comment: @BrtH : ok thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the source and drain are not marked in some way then you would assume that the device is symmetric, meaning that the source and drain can be interchanged and neither is connected to the substrate.

In this case, the terminal that is **lower** in voltage will be the source for an NMOS transistor and the terminal that is at a **higher** voltage will be the source for a PMOS transistor. \$V_{GS}\$ is always measured with respect to the terminal that is acting as the source.

And, yes, the roles of these two terminals can be swapped in real time as the voltages change. That can happen in a CMOS transmission gate, for example.

Comment: Very interesting. How did you learn this information (that if this is not written, the lower for NMOS is the source, the higher for the PMOS is the source) ?

Comment: In a field effect transistor, majority carriers flow from the source to the drain.  In N-channel devices, the majority carriers are electrons; in P-channel devices, they are holes.

Comment: I'd like to add that enchancement-mode and depletion-mode FETs are drawn differently. More here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/394333/how-can-i-tell-if-a-mosfet-is-enhancement-mode-or-depletion-mode

Comment: @MathieuKrisztian Be careful! I said the lower **voltage** terminal is source for NMOS and higher **voltage** terminal is source for PMOS. I learned this when I studied semiconductor physics and learned how an MOS transistor worked.

Comment: @Elliot Alderson  : ok I understand now.

Answer (score 2):

A four-terminal MOSFET, such as a typical one seen in a VLSI (integrated circuit) realization, is mostly symmetric, and its source/drain are established by the relative voltages on the two terminals that connect to the channel. An NMOS device, fabricated by implanting two N-regions in a p-well or p-substrate, has its source at the N-implant connected to a lower voltage. A pMOS device, fabricated with P-implants in an N-well, has its source at the P-implant experiencing a higher voltage.

This is not necessarily static either - in a transmission gate, the relative voltages of the two ends may change sign during circuit operation.

In discrete realizations, the device is no longer symmetric because one of the two ends of the channel is designated the source and is bonded to the body, creating a parasitic body diode structure. If the relative voltage of the source and drain is "wrong" (i.e. nFET having source voltage > drain voltage), the body diode will conduct.

Answer (score 1):

Context matters. In the context of CMOS logic designs (which is often where you find these seemingly ambiguous symbols) it is understood that VDD is on top, VSS is on bottom. Also, PMOS sources are tied to VDD and NMOS sources are tied to VSS. The drains of both PMOS and NMOS are tied to the output(s) of the gate or logic stage. The body diode connection is not shown. PMOS is distinguished from NMOS by having a "bubble" at the gate input, indicating that output (drain) has opposite polarity of input (gate).

I agree with the other answers as general answers, where context is not accounted for. But I wanted to just provide this additional comment about the context of CMOS logic designs.

PMOS, when on (gate low) pulls the output high. NMOS, when on (gate high) pulls the output low. That is just how CMOS logic works.

Comment: Your explanation is very useful as well.